# Как сделать, чтобы данные динамически менялись после выбора select?

Tags: javascript, html, input, select

Пытаюсь сделать калькулятор просчета стоимости
Есть такой код:

```js
const dataInput = document.querySelector("#data-input");
const resultInput = document.querySelector("#gcal-result");
const select = document.querySelector("#select");



select.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
  dataInput.oninput = function () {
    if (select.value === "Value-1") {
      dataInput.oninput = function () {
        resultInput.value = parseFloat(dataInput.value * 2).toFixed(2);
      };
    } else if (select.value === "Value-2") {
      dataInput.oninput = function () {
        resultInput.value = parseFloat(dataInput.value * 3).toFixed(2);
      };
    } else if (select.value === "Value-3") {
      dataInput.oninput = function () {
        resultInput.value = parseFloat(dataInput.value * 4).toFixed(2);
      };
    } else if (select.value === "Value-4") {
      dataInput.oninput = function () {
        resultInput.value = parseFloat(dataInput.value * 5).toFixed(2);
      };
    }
  };
});
```

```html
            <div class="calc-wrapp">
                        <div class="input">
                            <select id="select" class="form-control">
                                <option value="Value-1">1</option>
                                <option value="Value-2">2</option>
                                <option value="Value-3">3</option>
                                <option value="Value-4">4</option>
                            </select>
                            <input id="data-input">
                        </div>
                        <div class="input">
                            <p class="title">Результат:</p>
                            <input id="result-input" disabled>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Код работает корректно, но для того, что оно посчитало введенное значение нужно перевыбрать select. Как можно сделать, чтобы сразу при открытии калькулятора первое значение стояло по дефолту и сразу умножало значение. И может кто-то знает как можно динамически изменять результат, когда ввел, допустим, "3" и с одним select оно посчитало по одной формуле, а когда выбираешь другой select, то сразу же меняет значение на результат другой формулы. Буду признателен за помощь)

Comment: Вы смотрели на код в ответе на Ваш предыдущий вопрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем так много кода я не знаю.

```js
const dataInput = document.querySelector("#data-input");
const resultInput = document.querySelector("#result-input");
const select = document.querySelector("#select");

let recalc= () => {
    resultInput.value = (+dataInput.value * +select.value).toFixed(2);  
};

select.addEventListener("change", () => {
    recalc();
});

dataInput.oninput = () => {
    recalc();
};

recalc();
```

```html
<div class="calc-wrapp">
    <div class="input">
        <select id="select" class="form-control">
            <option value="2">Умножить на 2</option>
            <option value="3">Умножить на 3</option>
            <option value="4" selected>Умножить на 4</option>
            <option value="5">Умножить на 5</option>
        </select>
        <input id="data-input">
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <p class="title">Результат:</p>
        <input id="result-input" disabled>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ваш код работает также как и тот, что я написал

Comment: нет, не так же..

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы сразу при вводе в select оно рассчитывало по формуле. А в первый раз нужно перевыбрать select, чтобы оно посчитало

Comment: В селект нельзя ничего вводить. Можно только выбирать. По дефолту в селекте сейчас стоИт 1. В инпуте пустота, как следствие результат 0. Что не так? По дефолту надо другое значение? Так поставьте selected у нужного option

Comment: мне нужно, чтобы при выборе select рассчитывало по определенной формуле. По типу, если выбираешь 1 option, то введенное значение умножается на 2, при выборе второго option - на 3
Оно так и работает сейчас, но оно не считает сразу же, когда открываешь страницу с калькулятором. По дефолту стоит "1" и чтобы оно посчитало в первый раз нужно выбрать другой option и заново переключится на 1. То есть, оно отслеживает изменения, а мне нужно, чтобы сразу работало с тем select, что по дефолту стоит

Comment: @ross333 вы запускали мой пример? нет? с чего вы взяли что сейчас сразу при открытии калькулятора не считается значение?

Comment: Да, все работает, недосмотрел, спасибо Вам большое