# Нужно получить число из элемента вставленного через innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, input

Я получаю число путем вычитания `value` двух `input`. Есть такой код:

```js
const differenceResult = document.querySelector("#difference-result");
const calculateBtn = document.querySelector("#calculate-btn");
const price = document.querySelector("#total-price");


differenceResult.innerHTML = "<p class='res-num'>" + parseFloat(currentInput.value - lastInput.value).toFixed(2) + "</p>";

calculateBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  price.innerHTML = differenceResult * 2;
});
```

Как я могу обратиться к числу, которое я получаю при `parseFloat(currentInput.value - lastInput.value).toFixed(2)`, чтобы при клике на `calculateBtn` добавить его в `div price`.
Буду благодарен за помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно будет при клике вычислять по формуле, вставлять результат вычисления в переменную (любую), а потом уже ниже по коду, в этой же функции, оперировать этой переменной, в том числе и вставить в `differenceResult.innerHTML` и в `price.innerHTML`

---

если нужно получить значение до клика и во время клика - то надо создать отдельную функцию, которая будет делать вычисления и делать `return` этого значения. И уже результатом этой функции оперировать как при клике на кнопку, так и до (вот тут: `differenceResult.innerHTML = ...`)

Comment: Я правильно понял?: let calculationResult = () => { return (differenceResult.innerHTML = "<p class='res-num'>" + parseFloat(currentInput.value - lastInput.value).toFixed(2) +"</p>")};

Comment: нет. возвращать надо "чистое" значение. Без всяких `<p class='res-num'>` без всяких `differenceResult.innerHTML =`.  **только число**. Чтобы именно число, где нужно, можно было и обернуть в HTML и произвести вычисления и разные другие манипуляции.

Comment: @ross333 к тому же это есть в примере в ответе, который я вам уже писал: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1376196/191482 ...вполне можно было сделать вывод

Comment: окей, спасибо Вам